# how to create cookie inside embedded iframe in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, cookies, nginx

I try to create an embed code that can track of user behaviours, but there is an obstacle, here is my code, so they can embed in every web site

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var node = document.createElement("iframe");
        node.async = "true";
        node.src ="http://server1.tarytis.com/chat?q=529cb81960c488ee048b4567";
        node.frameBorder = "0";
        node.scrolling = "no";
        node.style.position = "absolute";
        node.style.bottom = "0px";
        node.style.right = "0px";
        document.body.appendChild(node);
    }
</script>
```

After I add my code into a webpage, that has different parent domain name, I cannot create a cookie, with cookie's domain attribute name of `server1.tarytis.com`, Google Chrome does not allow to set cookie inside an `iframe`. I don't know why and I have no idea how Google, Yandex and other websites manages this code. By the way, I have nginx server.

Comment: @brbcoding in firefox it is okay, but I cannot say the same when it is in chrome

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if there is an exception around this, but I believe you violate the Same Origin Policy by trying to set a cookie from a 3rd party domain.

This is why browsers will reject your cookie.